# Scrapy Spider only pulling the first value from item container

Tags: python, css, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape pricing info for comic books. What I'm ending up with is a Spider that scrapes through all instances of the top css selector, and then returns the desired value from only the first instance of the selector that contains the pricing info I'm after.

My end goal is to be able to create a pipeline to feed an SQLite db with title, sku, price, and url for the actual listing. Here is my code:

```
class XmenscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'finalscrape'
allowed_domains = ['mycomicshop.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=222421']

def parse(self, response):
    for item in response.css('td.highlighted'):
        yield {
            'title' : response.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="sku"]/@content').get()
            }
    
    
    next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract()[1]
    if next_page is not None:
        yield resonse.follow(next_page, callback- self.parse)
```

My output looks like this:

```
   {'title': '100 Bullets (1999 DC Vertigo) 1 CGC 9.8'}
    2022-01-24 13:53:04 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
    https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=222421>
    {'title': '100 Bullets (1999 DC Vertigo) 1 CGC 9.8'}
    2022-01-24 13:53:04 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
    https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=222421>
    {'title': '100 Bullets (1999 DC Vertigo) 1 CGC 9.8'}
    2022-01-24 13:53:04 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
    https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=222421>
    {'title': '100 Bullets (1999 DC Vertigo) 1 CGC 9.8'}
    2022-01-24 13:53:04 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
    https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=222421>
    {'title': '100 Bullets (1999 DC Vertigo) 1 CGC 9.8'}
```

If you look at the URL I'm trying to scrape, you can see that I'm only getting the desired value from the first  tag, despite the spider iterating through the five instances of it on the page. I have a feeling that this is a simple solution, but I'm at whit's end here. Any ideas on what would probably be a simple fix?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relative xpath to `item`.

```py
import scrapy


class XmenscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'finalscrape'
    allowed_domains = ['mycomicshop.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=222421']

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css('td.highlighted'):
            yield {
                # 'title': response.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="sku"]/@content').get()
                'title': item.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="name"]/@content').get()
            }

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Note: You only loop over the highlighted items, and since the next page doesn't have any you won't get anything from it.